# Why won't it expand both tar.gz files?

Tags: python, tar

I have two tar.gz files, 2014_SRS.tar.gz and 2013_SRS.tar.gz. Each of the files contains a folder called SRS, which is full of text files. I downloaded these from an ftp server. I want to unzip them automatically in Python. This is my code:

```
import re
import ftplib
import os
import time
import tarfile
import sys

print('1')

tar = tarfile.open('2014_SRS.tar.gz')
tar.extractall()
tar.close()

print('2')

tar = tarfile.open('2013_SRS.tar.gz')
tar.extractall()
tar.close()

print('3')
```

This code only opens the second file. How do I fix it to open both files?

Also, I tried using a for loop to run through the whole directory. The code is shown below.

```
for i in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
     if i.endswith(".tar.gz"): 
         tar = tarfile.open(i, "r:gz")
         tar.extractall()
         tar.close()
```

However this gave me an EOFError. In addition, before I ran bit of code, I was able to unzip both files manually. However, after I run it, and after the code gives me an error, I cannot unzip the 2014_SRS file manually anymore. How do I fix this?

Comment: Do the contents of the files have the same names? If so, I'd expect extracting the second file will overwrite the results of extracting the first file. But without knowing more about the files it will almost certainly be impossible for anyone to help you.

Comment: put each file in a different directory.  Repeat your code and compare output files

Comment: @Blckknght The contents of the files have the same name. But no matter how I order it (i.e whether I extract from 2014_SRS or 2013_SRS), I will only end up with the folder from 2013_SRS

Comment: You can pass a `path` parameter to `extractall` ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/tarfile.html#tarfile.TarFile.extractall)). You could just strip off the `.tar.gz` and use that as your path param.

Comment: any error raised when open '2014_SRS.tar.gz'? what's the python version you use?

Comment: I use python version 3. There are no problems when I open it manually, or have it be the only file I want to open (i.e removing the block of code that opens the 2013_SRS file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this may not answer your specific question as to why both files could not be unzipped with your code , the following is one way to unzip a list of tar.gz files.

```
import tarfile, glob

srcDir = "/your/src/directory" 
dstDir = "/your/dst/directory"

for f in glob.glob(srcDir + "/*.gz"):

    t = tarfile.open(f,"r:gz")

    for member in t.getmembers():
            t.extract(member,dstDir)
    t.close()
```

Comment: Can you explain the path?

Comment: I meant the absolute path of the source directory where the tar.gz files are and also the absolute path of where we want the files to be extracted to. These could for example be /Users/xyz/workspace.

Comment: Do you get any error ? Can you be more specific? Are you sure the directory has tar gz files

Comment: So I use the block of code you provided, setting the srsDirectory and the dstDirectory as the same. I verified the path in terminal. I am sure that the directory that I inputed has tar.gz files. However, when I run the code, nothing pops up on the console, and the files are unzipped. I put print statements around the code, but again, nothing shows up in the console.

Comment: Hm, so the files are unzipped and extracted ? What print statements did you add. The above code works fine for me .

Comment: Perhaps I should upload the files? If I can.

Comment: I added a print statement right before the first for loop, right before t = tarfile.open(f,"r:gz"), and right after the second for loop. Is the asterisk in srcDir + "/*.gz" supposed to be there?

Comment: Yes.The asterisk is fine. What are you printing?

Comment: print('1'), print('2'), print('3') as indicators